# How can I validate two variables with Java 8 Lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8

How can I do this with Java 8 Lambdas:

```
Optional<String> code;
if (accountType.requiresCode() && (!code.isPresent() || empty(code.get()))) {
    new IllegalArgumentException("Account type " + accountType + " requires code");
}
```

Comment: Optionals can do the job !
http://blog.jhades.org/java-8-how-to-use-optional/

Comment: `code` is an Optional<String>

Comment: And what's the problem with the above code? What would you gain by using lambdas, and where?

Comment: There's no problem with this code. But I wanted to know if I could gain anything by using Lambdas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* rewrite the code as

```
Optional<String> code;
if (accountType.requiresCode()) code.filter(x->!empty(x)).orElseThrow(
  () -> new IllegalArgumentException("Account type " + accountType + " requires code")
);
```

or, assuming that your `empty(code.get())` actually meant `code.get().isEmpty()`:

```
Optional<String> code=Optional.empty();
if (accountType.requiresCode()) code.filter(x->!x.isEmpty()).orElseThrow(
  () -> new IllegalArgumentException("Account type " + accountType + " requires code")
);
```

But it doesn’t really add to readability. Lambdas aren’t always better than ordinary code.

Comment: I like the `filter` idea, but I think that checking `isPresent()` would be more readable. `if (accountType.requiresCode() && !code.filter(x->!empty(x)).isPresent()) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
if (accountType.requiresCode() && code.map(this::empty).orElse(true))
```

but I'm not sure it makes the code more readable.

Comment: Isn’t this what `Optional.filter` is for? E.g. `code.filter(s -> !empty(s)).isPresent()`; using `map` and `orElse` with `boolean`s feels so wrong…

Comment: Using filter is indeed another solution. I just didn't think about it. I agree it's cleaner. But I'm still not sure it makes the code more readable.

Comment: I guess, in this case none of these lambda using variants make the code more readable…

Answer (score 0):

According to this question [Valid usage of Optional type in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447827/valid-usage-of-optional-type-in-java-8) Optional is not a good choice here, though technically possible.

You can rewrite using StringUtils to the much nicer:

```
final String code = getCodeFromSomething();
if (accountType.requiresCode() && StringUtils.isEmpty(code)) {
    new IllegalArgumentException("Account type " + accountType + " requires code");
}
```