# Extracting a key/value pair from json using streams

Tags: java, json, functional-programming, java-stream

My json file is like this

```
  {
    "Parent1": {
    "Child1":"TRUE",
    "RandomKey":"TEST-111"
   },
     "Parent2": {
      "Child1":"TRUE",
     "AnotherRandomKey":"TEST-432"
    }
  }
```

My goal is to extract first occurrence of Child1 from either Parent1 or Parent2 depending on whatever exists, if both exists it should just get the first.

I have the following code written in java but it is always returning false. Not sure what i am doing wrong

```
   final var content = Jackson.getObjectMapper().readTree(//json link);

   Stream.concat(
         Optional.ofNullable(content.at("/Parent1/Child1")).stream(),
         Optional.ofNullable(content.at("/Parent2/Child1")).stream())
        .map(JsonNode::asBoolean)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(false);
```

I am trying to combine both streams and just find the first occurence of Child1 and return the boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for some reason, [`JsonNode.asBoolean()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#asBoolean()) is implemented to be case-sensitive. Hence, parses `"TRUE"` as `false`.

> Method that will try to convert value of this node to a Java boolean. JSON booleans map naturally; integer numbers other than `0` map to true, and `0` maps to `false` and `Strings` `"true"` and `"false"` map to corresponding values.

It's not very intuitive because standard JDK wrapper type `Boolean` performs parsing in the case-insensitive manner.

As a workaround, we can extract a `String` from a node, and then apply `Boolean.parseBoolean`.

***Note:*** there's no need to create an `Optional` in order to generate a stream. In this case, `Optional.ofNullable(content.at())` is an abuse of optional (*for more details on the usage of optional* [*see*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73424610/optionalt-as-a-record-parameter-in-java/73425004#73425004)).

We can use [`Stream.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of(T...)) for that purpose.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String message = """
        {
            "Parent1": {
            "Child1":"TRUE",
                "RandomKey":"TEST-111"
        },
            "Parent2": {
            "Child1":"TRUE",
                "AnotherRandomKey":"TEST-432"
        }
        }""";
    
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode content = mapper.readTree(message);
    
    boolean result = Stream.of(content.at("/Parent1/Child1"), content.at("/Parent2/Child1"))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(JsonNode::asText)
        .map(Boolean::parseBoolean)
        .filter(value -> value) // guarding against the case when node "Parent1" doesn't exist
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(false);

    System.out.println(result);
    
}
```

*Output:*

```
true
```

Comment: For some reason i am getting t.java:65: error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    [javac]                 .map(JsonNode::asText)
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]     (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
    [javac]       incompatible types: Stream<JsonNode> cannot be converted to String)

Let me retry and update you

Comment: @Saad That's the Jackson-dependency I'm using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.13.3.

Comment: I believe it is not working if input does not contain the Parent1 json, if we only provide it Parent2, i am getting false.

Comment: @Saad You're right. Fixed the code by adding a `filter()` before `findFirst()`. `filter(value -> value)` will retain `Boolean` objects with a value `true`. That would guard against the case when node `Parent1` doesn't exist.