# Java optional stream collector to list from two sources else null?

Tags: java, list, stream, option-type, collectors

I apologize in advance if this question has been asked, but I have been struggling to figure this out for a few hours now (googling everything I can) and really hope someone could help.

I am trying to collect two String values, which I am trying to get from a source, in to a single String, and return `null` if these values do not exist (`source.getA` returns `null`).

So far, I have come up with this code:

```
if (source.getA() != null && source.getB() != null) {
    target.setAAndB(Stream.of(source.getA(), source.getB())
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
} else {
    target.setAandB(null);
}
```

How do I turn this in to a nice looking chain? I know there is a way, but I feel like I am missing a trick here.

**EDIT:**

```
target.setAandB(
        Optional.of(
                Stream.of(source.getA(), source.getB())
                        .map(String::valueOf)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
        ).orElse(null)
);
```

Made a bit of progress, but here the `orElse` will not work, because the collector still returns a string with two `null` strings combined.

**EDIT 2**:

Thank you all for your answers, I found them very valuable and some valuable things to consider.

Comment: I'd like to understand what getA and getB functions are.

And why you are using streams for just 2 values.

Comment: So basically you're creating a Stream and Collector just in order to concatenate two Strings. You're clearly **misusing** the Stream API.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko but do you know, how I can turn this in to a chain without the `if`?

Comment: @e-dudins It implies you don't care if you're **abusing** Streams and Optional or not? Did hear about ***clean-coding***? Optional and Streams should not be used to hide conditions.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko no, I care a lot about this stuff.

Comment: @e-dudins `I care a lot` - Then you should not try to replace conditional with something which is not meant for such purpose.

Comment: @e-dudins: to check for not null you should use 
  *.filter(s -> s!=null)*  
  Still I don't understand why you use map(String::valueOf). don't getA and getB already return a string?

Comment: `target.setAandB(source.getA() != null && source.getB() != null? source.getA() + " " + source.getB(): null);`

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator can be used

```
target.setAandB(Objects.isNull(source.getA()) && Objects.isNull(source.getB()) ? null 
           : Stream.of(source.getA(), source.getB())
                  .map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no benefits in hiding conditional logic by using Optional.

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458582/17949945) by [@StuartMarks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441122/stuart-marks), Java and OpenJDK developer.

> *The primary use of* `Optional` *is as follows:*
>
> Optional is intended to provide a limited mechanism for library method return types where
> there is a clear need to represent "no result," and where using null
> for that is overwhelmingly likely to cause errors.
>
> A typical **code smell** is, instead of the code using method chaining to
> handle an `Optional` returned from some method, it **creates** an `Optional`
> from something that's nullable, in order to **chain methods** and **avoid
> conditionals**.

It is not justifiable to create Optional to avoid *null-checks*. It obscures the logic and makes your code harder to read.

And using Streams just in order to concatenate **only two** `Strings` is clearly an overkill. We have enough tools for that, apart from streams.

That said, your code might be written like that:

```
if (source.getA() != null && source.getB() != null) {
    target.setAandB(source.getA() + " " + source.getB());
} else {
    target.setAandB(null);
}
```

Alternatively, you can introduce a method responsible for generating this String:

```
public String getAB() {
    
    return source.getA() == null || source.getB() == null ? null :
        source.getA() + " " + source.getB();
}
```

***Note:*** that if `getA()` and `getB()` are not plain getters, and `source` object does something behind the scenes to fetch the data, you need to store both into local variables instead of fetching twice.

Comment: …and even `String.join(" ", source.getA().toString(), source.getB().toString()` can be replaced by a simpler `source.getA() + " " + source.getB()`

Comment: @Holger You're right, overlooked that.

Comment: Thank you for your input, some things to consider.