# Exctract the Stream from an Optional<Stream>

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

Suppose I have an `Optional` containing a `Stream`:

```java
Optional<Stream<Integer>> optionalStream = Optional.of(Stream.of(1, 2, 3));
```

Now I need to extract the `Stream` itself. If the `Optional` is empty, you want to get an empty Stream.

I'm looking of is something like `flatStream()` that performs transformation in one step. How can I do this?

*My current attempt:*

```java
Stream<Integer> stream = optionalStream.stream().flatMap(Function.identity());
```

---

#### The Context of the Problem

In my real scenario, I have something like this, which gives me a `Stream<Optional<Foo>>`:

```
stream.findFirst().map(e -> e.getChildren())
```

Comment: Why not call `get()` / `orElseX()` ?

Comment: `optionalStream.orElse(Stream.of({}).stream` or similar, not sure about creating an empty stream

Comment: What's a more "beautiful" way?

Comment: Personally, I would not use an optional wrapping a stream. Use only a stream.

Comment: How do you end up with an `Optional<Stream>` other than artificially creating it like in your example? You must have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: that was just an example, in my real scenario it makes somewhat more sense.
there I have something like:
`stream.findFirst().map(e -> e.getChildren())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could use the `orElseGet()` method:

```
optionalStream.orElseGet(()->Stream.empty())
```

Comment: I didn’t think of that, but thats exacly what I looked for.
With method reference it looks even cleaner IMHO.
`optionalStream.orElseGet(Stream::empty)`

Answer (score 8):

## Use [`Stream.empty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#empty())

It doesn't make sense to wrap a `Stream` with an `Optional`.

An `Optional` allows to interact safely with the result of the method call, which might not produce the data. And empty Optional represents the case when the data is absent.

A `Stream` can also be empty, and it represents the absents of data perfectly fine without a need of being packed into an `Optional`.

Use `Stream.empty()` as a return value for your method.

*You also might want to check these references:*

- [Uses for Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/17949945)
- [Valid usage of Optional type in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458582/17949945)

#### Addressing the Question-update

## [`Optional.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#stream())

The best solution to the problem is to **eliminate the problem**.

The spirit of the answer remains unchanged: don't create an `Optional<Stream<T>>` and there would be no need to deal with it.

Java 9 `Optional.stream()` comes to the rescue. Apply `stream()` after `findFirst()`, and you would get either a singleton-stream containing a value captured by `findFirst()`, or an empty stream. And then you can perform any transformation you need.

So, instead of this:

```
stream.findFirst().map(e -> e.getChildren())
```

Do the following:

```
stream.findFirst().stream().flatMap(Foo::getChildren)
```

## Stream.limit()

Alternatively, as suggested by *@Holger* instead of `findFirt()` you can apply `limit(1)` and continue to chain stream-operation. This approach would work with JDK 8.

```
stream.limit(1).flatMap(Foo::getChildren)
```

Comment: I get an optional by having a stream, getting the first item of the stream (resulting in an optional) and then mapping the optional to its children (resulting in the aforementioned optionalStream)

Comment: @DarioViva Sounds like you're using `findFist()` and then generating a `Stream` from the element wrapped with the resulting `Optional`, right? If so I would advise to make use of the Java 9 [`Optional.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#stream()), i.e. apply `findFirst().stream() ... `. The best solution to the problem is to **eliminate the problem**.

Comment: @DarioViva I've the description of your real case from the comment to the question and addressed it in the answer (see the update).